# CSS Align to right a list in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-lists

I have a list inside a table, I want to align this list to the right, it sounds easy, but some reason is not working.

This is my code:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
td{
  vertical-align: top;
  width:300px
}
.ri{
  background-color:#AAA;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
 <td>Equipo</td>
 <td class="ri">
  <ul name="s_truck" style="height: 200px;overflow-y: auto;width: 140px;">
         <li>
            <label for="chk_2013035"><input type="checkbox" name="trk[]" id="chk_2013035"> CA046</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <label for="chk_2013051"><input type="checkbox" name="trk[]" id="chk_2013051"> CA047</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <label for="chk_2013072"><input type="checkbox" name="trk[]" id="chk_2013072"> CA055</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <label for="chk_2013031"><input type="checkbox" name="trk[]" id="chk_2013031"> CA056</label>
         </li>     
  </ul>
 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

On jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aftc6vq8/7/

Why is not working?

How to fix it?

Comment: why not use the table properly if you are going to use it: https://jsfiddle.net/05148s0x/2/, otherwise you can move your `ul` right by adding `margin-left:auto`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-align` does not align block level elements like a `ul`

Change it's display to `inline-block`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 300px
}

.ri {
  background-color: #AAA;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Equipo</td>
    <td class="ri">
      <ul name="s_truck" style="height: 200px;overflow-y: auto;width: 140px;">
        <li>
          <label for="chk_2013035"><input type="checkbox" name="trk[]" id="chk_2013035"> CA046</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="chk_2013051"><input type="checkbox" name="trk[]" id="chk_2013051"> CA047</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="chk_2013072"><input type="checkbox" name="trk[]" id="chk_2013072"> CA055</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="chk_2013031"><input type="checkbox" name="trk[]" id="chk_2013031"> CA056</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

You've forced your list to be 140px wide, so it only makes it halfway across the cell. Change this line

```
<ul name="s_truck" style="height: 200px;overflow-y: auto;width: 140px;">
```

to this

```
<ul name="s_truck" style="height: 200px;overflow-y: auto;">
```

Comment: would love some feedback around why I'm being downvoted when the solution I've given works just fine.

Comment: "Works fine" is, shrug, OK....but it's not really solving the OPs *actual* problem. Assume, in the absence of evidence to the contrary, that the width was there for a reason. ...and resolve it in light of that.

Comment: Meh, feels to me like we each made just as much of an assumption of the intended layout as the other. Now that I look over it again, I actually feel like it's more likely that OP would want to set the width of the <td> and not the <ul>, so that there isn't a bunch of unused gray area. But we'll likely never know so... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯